# tags with plus (+)

Tags: support, tags

The tags help box (shown when editing tags) says tags can contain +, but when I type a tag like "lost+found", it tries to use two tags, "lost" and "found".

Answer (score 1):

Tags can contain plus, but only at the ends, e.g. [c++](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

In general you should avoid this.

Comment: Any chance the help box could be more wordy to explain this exception for plus?  Thanks.

Comment: `lost+found` is as natural to unix sysadmins as `c++` is to programmers. `lost-found` looks wrong, but it's at least comprehensible; I'd find `lost-and-found` less grating, but it wouldn't turn up in searches the way `lost-found` would.